# Laravel 4 Aliases in custom classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i want to use the alias classes on laravel 4 "facades" like App::method , Config::method.

Well the thing is that i create a custom class and i have to import the namespaces like

```
<?php

namespace Face\SocialHandlers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class FacebookHandler implements SocialHandlerInterface {

    public function registrar($perfil) {
        Config::get('facebook');
    }

}
```

is there any way to use those classes like in controllers or routes files of the framework ?

like

```
<?php

namespace Face\SocialHandlers;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class FacebookHandler implements SocialHandlerInterface {

    public function registrar($perfil) {
        Config::get('facebook');
    }

}
```

Cya

ps: sry for my english

Comment: where is that class will be used ??

Comment: i edit the post to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `use Config;` instead of the more verbose `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` and the autoloader should handle it correctly.

Comment: It works perfect =) well is less verbose but i have to import the classes , what i'm looking for is like for example a controller class that can call any alias ( definded in the alias array ) without have to import the classes

Comment: Well thx i guess i have to allways import the classes , like @dennis says i can do a master class that imports everything i need and then extend that class so i don't need to import it in every class.

thx to all for your time =)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a tip, **you shouldn't hardcode dependencies in your code**. Instead of using the facades, you could create an `"ConfigInterface"` to get the common dependencies you need. Then create a `"LaravelConfig class"` *(Or Laravel4Config.php)* and implement those methods.

#### For a Quick Fix Answer, "catch the underliying facade instance":

```
namespace Face\SocialHandlers;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class FacebookHandler implements SocialHandlerInterface {
    protected $config;
    protected $app;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::getFacadeRoot();
        $this->app = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::getFacadeRoot();
    }

    public function registrar($perfil) {
        $this->config->get('facebook');
    }

}
```

#### For a Real Answer, *maybe tedious*, but good in the long run, instead of using the facades use an interface.

```
interface SocialConfigInterface
{
    public function getConfigurationByKey($key)
}
```

Then

```
class Laravel4Config implements SocialConfigInterface
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::getFacadeRoot(); //<-- hard coded, but as expected since it's a class to be used with Laravel 4
    }

    public function getConfigurationByKey($key)
    {
        return $this->config->get($key);
    }
}
```

And Your Code

```
namespace Face\SocialHandlers;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class FacebookHandler implements SocialHandlerInterface {
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(SocialConfigInterface $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function registrar($perfil) {
        $this->config->get('facebook');
    }

}
```

This way, if you want to change between frameworks you just need to create a `SocialConfigInterface` Implementation, or imagine the scenario where Laravel 5 wont use Facades, you want your code to be independent of "outsider changes" this is inversion of control IoC

Answer (score 0):

First run,

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

This will add your class namespace to `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`. Now locate the entry for your class in this classmap array and get the proper namespace from there.

For example, you will get something like,

```
'Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\App' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/App.php',
```

For this particular entry you have an alias in `app/config/app.php`

```
'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
```

At the same way, locate your entry and use an alias in `app/config/app.php`.

Comment: I see but if i do this i will be creating an alias right ? , the only thing i want is not having to import the namespaces of the clases that i want to use

Like "Config" or "App" , for example if you create a new controller you can call the Config class without having to import it.

Again sry for my english

and thx for your answer =)

Comment: what I meant is that when you put some code for example in a controller "HomeController.php" , you just call Config:: , if I delete the  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config; on my class i can't call it.
I'm just asking if there is any way to call Config without importing "use" it

Comment: You can call any alias using their deined name, which is defined in ``app.php`` without using namespace. The example is ``Config::``. Like this you can define your class also. If alias not defined, you have to use the namespace in specific controller. Why you are trying to delete laravel's inbuilt alias?

Comment: Well in my custom class located in `app/customFolder/MyClass.php` ( example ) , if there i call for example `Config::` laravel tells me that he can't find the class , so i have to add the use statement for import that class . What i do is go to the `app.php` go to the `aliases array` an look at the alias namespace then i use the namespace of the alias on my custom class.

In the case of `App:_` , i look into the aliases array

`'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',`

and in my custom class import it using `use 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a folder, or place a class wherever already is listed for autoload. Me, for exemple, have this class `PDFMaker`, that uses a DomPDF Laravel implementation. I created a folder named `libraries` and put the path to it (under the `app` folder) in the `autoload:classmap` key on `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/libraries",
        "app/models",
        "app/helpers",
        "app/database/migrations"
    ]
```

I did the same with `commands` for artisan commands! When you do that, you only have to declare a new object for any class under that folder, or call it in a static way, if the class has defined static methods. Something like `Class::method`.

Hope it helps you, have a nice day! :D

EDIT: After that, don't forget the `dump-autoload` for placing the new class in autoload scope.

EDIT 2:  Remember that once you've put the class on autoload, it will be in same scope the others, so you won't have to import it to other, neither others to it!

Comment: what I meant is that when you put some code for example in a controller "HomeController.php" , you just call Config:: , if I delete the  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config; on my class i can't call it.
I'm just asking if there is any way to call Config without importing "use" it

Comment: You want to call the class without importing the namespace? Is that correct?

Comment: Yup but i want to call laravel classes from my custom class located in app/CustomFolder/Class.php.

Sry i'm really a beginner in laravel and frameworks.

Thx for you time btw =)

Comment: Look, in EVERY programming language (OO) I ever worked with, you **need** to import the namespace to work with the class. **BUT**, Laravel let you create a Facede for it. It's the only two ways I think that might be possible.

Comment: ... just ocurred to me: If the problem is having to import on every single place, you can import just once in a parent class and let every of your extra classes extends them. You're only able to use `Config::` that way cause it's already imported in `app.php`.

Comment: Reading you other comment in another answer made me realize what you are  really asking. Look at the second edit.

Comment: Nice =D , thx for your idea it was so simple why i didn't think about that : ( thx so much =D

so resuming in the parent class i do all the importing `use blablabla`
and on the child classes i can use the imports of the parent class =D ?

Comment: Yeah, or you can use it by the `composer.json` on the `autoload` key, as I mentioned on the **EDIT 2** on the same answer.

Comment: w8 , i already have my class on psr-0 autoload , and i have to use the config namespace :S

Comment: Your class is on `composer.json`'s autoload:classmap?

Comment: ´"autoload": {"psr-0": {"Face" : "app/"}´

Face folder its in `app/Face` , inside i have 2 extra folders 
`app/Face/Servicios` and `app/Face/SocialHandlers` well classes inside `app/Face/Servicios` use `namespace Face\Servicios;` and classes inside `app/Face/SocialHandlers` use `namespace Face\SocialHandlers;`

Comment: That's strange: my composer.json has this autoload node right in the root. Strange, at least...

Answer (score 0):

You can also prefix the class names with a backslash, to use the global namespace: `\Config::get('facebook')` and `\App::someMethod()` will work without the need to add a `use` statement, regardless of the file's namespace.